# How can I get a char of a String in delphi 7?

Tags: string, delphi

This is something that should be easey but I just can´t get it work.
I come from java so maby I have a error in my thinking here.
What I want to do is that I have a string with two letters like 't4' or 'pq'.
Now I just want to get each of the chracters in the string as an own string.
 So I do:

```
firstString := myString[0];
```

but I don´t even get this compiled.
So I figured that they start counting form 1 and put 1 as an index.
Now I do this in a while loop and the first time I go through it it works fine. Then the second time the results are just empty or wrong numbers. 
What am I missing here?
(I also tried copy but that doesn´t work either!)

```
while i < 10 do
          begin
                te := 'te';
                a := te[1];
                b := te[2];
               i := i +1;
          end;
```

the first loop a is 't' and b is 'e' as I would expect. The second time a is '' and b ist 't' which I don´t understand!

Comment: *"Then the second time the results are just empty or wrong numbers."* - Show us your code

Comment: @MartinPrikryl edited my question

Comment: In your code, what result do you get, and what result do you expect?

Comment: @Amadan edited my question

Comment: The code does not look wrong. But if you do use "myString[0]", NOTE that first letter/char in the string has index 1. It won't compile if you use 0.

Comment: The code you show (the `while` loop) doesn't expose the erroneous behaviour you claim it does.

Comment: Please don't post fake code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are 1-based, not zero-based.  Try the following, after adding StrUtils to your Uses list (for DupeString):

```
var
  MyString : String;
begin
  MyString := '12345';
  Caption := StringOfChar(MyString[1], 8) + ':' + DupeString(Copy(MyString, 3, 2), 4);
```

You could split it up to mke it easier to follow, of course:

```
var
  MyString,
  S1,
  S2,
  S3: String;
begin
  MyString := '12345';
  S1 := StringOfChar(MyString[1], 8);
  S2 := Copy(MyString, 3, 2);
  S3 := DupeString(S2, 4);
  Caption :=  S1 + ':' + S3;
```